# Alamofire: Cancel (suspend) file upload

Tags: ios, alamofire

I am uploading a file using Alamofire as such:

```
    Alamofire.Manager.upload(
        APIManager.Router.UploadFileRoute,
        multipartFormData : { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: audioData, name: "file", fileName: "file.m4a", mimeType: "audio/m4a")
        }, encodingCompletion: { result in
            switch result {
            case .Success(let request, _, _):
              break
            case .Failure(let encodingError):
              break
            }
    })
```

How do I cancel (suspend) this file upload once it has begun?

The [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#request) suggests that I call suspend() on the Request object, but how do I get a hold of the Alamofire.Request object using the file upload API above? This API doesn't return any Alamofire.Request object.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the request is ready only after the encoding (see comments inline)

```
Alamofire.Manager.upload(
    APIManager.Router.UploadFileRoute,
    multipartFormData : { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: audioData, name: "file", fileName: "file.m4a", mimeType: "audio/m4a")
    }, encodingCompletion: { result in
        switch result {
        case .Success(let request, _, _):
          // Reference the request here (will get here immediately)
             request.responseJSON { response in
                  // This closure executes only after request succeeds or fails
             }
          break
        case .Failure(let encodingError):
          break
        }
})
```